# Why is "rm" so much slower than deleting files via the File Manager?

Tags: bash, filemanager, rm

I witnessed that deleting directories (with the size of a couple of gigabytes) which contain many files is very slow when using **rm**. It takes up to several minutes!
When deleting the same folder via the File Manager, the job is done within a second. (It takes another second to empty the trash afterwards.)

What is the reason for this?

Comment: How did you do the experiment? Were you starting from an empty disk cache or with all the directories in the cache both times? If `rm` had to load everything from disk but the file manager did everything in memory, that would explain the difference.

Comment: A directory (~5 GB) on an external USB hard drive containing more than 3000 Files and a lot of sub-directories.

Comment: Hmmm... next time you try to delete a folder with many files, try deleting using SHIFT+DELETE key on that folder. It will ask if you want to permanently remove those files. That will then show you a progress bar showing you how long it takes to delete. You should notice that it takes just as long as `rm` does. AFAIK file-managers just use `rm` in the background.

Comment: @schrobe This isn't the relevant information. Was the data in the cache before each experiment?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't access the directories before, so I guess not. Anyway, this wasn't a real "experiment" but I could see significant differences. Since it turned outthere is no trivial answer, I can set up an "experiment" and precisly measure the time (and ensure the same memory conditions).

Comment: I've had the opposite experience where using `rm` is near instant, but using a file manager can take a long time.

Answer (score 11):

The `rm` command actually removes the files, File Manager only moves the files to the trash. It is only when you empty the trash that you see the actual time that `rm` took to delete the files. So put simply, moving files is quicker than deleting. File Manager moves files while `rm` removes them.

Comment: But as I said: Emptying the trash doesn't talk long either.  
My guess: Clearing the trash does actually take a long time, but it is shown empty even though the rm command is still running in the background.

Comment: But `rm` simply unlinks the files, no?